# Independence of sum and quotient of exponential variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent random variables each following an exponential distribution with the same parameter $\lambda$. (They both have density function $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x > 0$.) I know that in this case the variables $S = X_1 + X_2$ and $Q = X_1/X_2$ are independent, and I know how to prove this by a calculation with a Jacobian.

I would like an intuitive explanation of this fact, if this is possible.

Here is a possible real-world interpretation of the problem. Large numbers of pedestrians walk past a shop (at a constant rate), and occasionally one will randomly enter the shop. Call $X_1$ the time it takes before the first customer enters, and $X_2$ the additional time it takes for the second customer to enter. Then the ratio $X_1/X_2$ of these times is independent of the total time $X_1 + X_2$ it took for the second customer to enter.

This result is so simple that it seems plausible there is an explanation with minimal calculation. However, I can't figure out why it should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_1+X_2=k$ then the conditional distribution of $X_1$ is uniform on $(0,k)$ - this is true for i.i.d exponential random variables but not true in general.

So given $X_1+X_2=k$, you have $\dfrac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}$ uniform on $(0,1)$.

This does not depend on $k$, so $\dfrac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent, thus $\dfrac{X_1+X_2}{X_1}$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent, $1+\dfrac{X_2}{X_1}$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent, $\dfrac{X_2}{X_1}$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent, and thus $\dfrac{X_1}{X_2}$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent.

Comment: For the first statement note that $\lambda \exp(-\lambda x) \times \lambda \exp(-\lambda (k-x)) = \lambda^2 \exp(-k)$, i.e. a constant with respect to $x \in(0,k)$

Comment: This answer sheds a lot of light on what's really going on. I've checked the first statement by computation. Now I'll have to see if I can understand it intuitively.

Comment: Okay, I think it's pretty clear. If you know the second customer entered after one hour, there's no time that's likelier than any other for the first customer to have entered.